How to Implement Softmax, in python, whereby the input are signed 8 integers
I am trying to implement a softmax function that takes in signed int8 input and returns a signed int8 output array.
The current implementation I have going is this,
 import numpy as np

def softmax_int8(inputs):
    inputs = np.array(inputs, dtype=np.int8)
    
    x = inputs.astype(np.int32)
    x_max = np.max(x)
    x_shifted = x - x_max
    scale_factor = 2 ** 14 
    exp_limit = 16
    exp_x = np.clip(x_shifted + exp_limit, 0, None)
    exp_x = (1 << exp_x)
    sum_exp_x = np.sum(exp_x)

    if sum_exp_x == 0:
        sum_exp_x = 1

    softmax_probs = (exp_x * scale_factor) // sum_exp_x
    max_prob = np.max(softmax_probs)
    min_prob = np.min(softmax_probs)
    range_prob = max_prob - min_prob if max_prob != min_prob else 1

    scaled_probs = ((softmax_probs - min_prob) * 255) // range_prob - 128
    outputs = scaled_probs.astype(np.int8)

    return outputs

I test it using this input, Input = [101, 49, 6, -34, -75, -79, -38, 120, -55, 115]
but I get this output array([-128, -128, -128, -128, -128, -128, -128,  127, -128, -121],dtype=int8).
My expected output is array([-57, -70, -79, -86, -92, -94, -88, -54, -91, -56], dtype=int8).
What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

I think there are different mathematical definitions of softmax in different contexts.

Wikipedia definition (on real numbers): exp(z) / sum(exp(z))
What I inferred from your code: (1<<(z-z_max + 16)) / sum((1 << (z-z_max + 16))) or something similar. 1<< === 2** obviously.

The major difference is the base number of the exponential. With base too high you are highly likely to get underflow and get a lot of -128. Besides there are also a biase that maps the result to [-128, 127] range, which is trival and less important
It's highly likely that the library that you takes test cases from use a different definition than both of above.
I did some testing with your test case and floating point definition of softmax with matplotlib, and the following expression gives a good fit:
softmax_naive = (np.exp(inarr / 128) / np.sum(np.exp(inarr / 128)) * 256) - 100

You can imagine that you probably need to do a >>7 to input bytes before doing 1<< 2-based exponential. To give completely identical result, surely you should dig into that library code, which I didn't have time to do.
Below are validation codes:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inarr = np.array([101, 49, 6, -34, -75, -79, -38, 120, -55, 115], dtype=np.int8).astype(np.double)
expected_arr = np.array([-57, -70, -79, -86, -92, -94, -88, -54, -91, -56], dtype=np.int8).astype(np.double)
print(expected_arr)

softmax_naive = (np.exp(inarr / 128) / np.sum(np.exp(inarr / 128)) * 256) - 100
print(softmax_naive - expected_arr)
plt.plot(inarr)
plt.plot(expected_arr)
plt.plot(softmax_naive)
plt.show()




what am I doing wrong?

You desire identical output to what
https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-NN/blob/main/Tests/UnitTest/generate_test_data.py
produces, but you didn't call the routines that it calls,
and you didn't specify parameters of x_in=5 and y_in=2.
You want to call generate_data() in
https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-NN/blob/main/Tests/UnitTest/softmax_settings.py
If you desire a somewhat different output format for those figures,
start by creating a
unit test
that successfully reproduces the figures of interest.
Then tweak your target code, while still keeping that test Green.
The test runner will help you to notice if / when a small edit broke something.

import numpy as np


def softmax(x):
    """
    Softmax函数实现
    """
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum()


# 假设的带符号8个整数输入
input_numbers = np.array([-2, 1, 3, -1, 0, 2, 4, -3])

softmax_result = softmax(input_numbers)

print(softmax_result)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
